# IPN POSTING : cannot receive post values from paypal

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

can anyone help me about IPN listener script. I have tried testing it using sandbox test tool for IPN but I always get an INVALID result but the HTTP status is 200. I also tried echoing the $_POST array but its empty..

heres my code

```
<?php


echo "<pre>".print_r($_POST,true)."</pre>\n";

$ipn_data=$_POST;

if((array_key_exists('test_ipn',$ipn_data)) && ($ipn_data['test_ipn']==1)){

    $url="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";

}
else{

    $url="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    }

    $request=curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($request,array
    (
        CURLOPT_URL=>$url,
        CURLOPT_POST=>true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>http_build_query(array('cmd'=>'_notify-validate')+ $ipn_data),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>TRUE,
        CURLOPT_HEADER=>FALSE,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false

    ));

    $result=curl_exec($request);
    $stat=curl_getinfo($request,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($request);

    echo $result;
    echo $stat;
    if($stat==200 && $result=='VERIFIED'){


        echo "VERIFIED";



    }




?>
```

Comment: Can we assume that you have [`rm = "2"`](https://cms.paypal.com/es/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id08A6HI0709B) in your payment method (button, shopping cart, etc) to change from `$_GET`(default) to `$_POST` -

Comment: If you go into your paypal account and look under the ipn responses, what are you getting?

Comment: ive tried to test it with the IPN test tool but still i cant get any responses..here is the url of my ipn listener http://occs.evsuit2013.com/ipn_listener.php ,you can try it if you want...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your problem is that you haven't enabled IPN in your merchant account?  'My Account' / 'Profile' / 'Selling Preferences' / 'Instant Payment Notification Preferences'. Enter your notification url and set message delivery to enabled.